# WorkManager get time of next scheduled work by tag

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) to schedule both periodic and one-time work, and I am tagging all of the work with the same tag so that I can identify it later:

```
workRequestBuilder.addTag("mywork");
```

With various work items enqueued, at various times in the future, I would like a way of querying the work queue to determine when the *next* work is scheduled to run for this particular tag (`"mywork"`).  Yes, I know that it will not be exact and will be subject to Doze etc, but it would still be useful to know when -- in the absence of other factors -- the work is likely to run.

I know how to query the work queue and pick out enqueued work items as follows, but I'm just not sure how to tell what time each work item is scheduled to run:

```
WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> workInfos = workManager.getWorkInfosByTag("mywork");

try {
    List<WorkInfo> workInfoList = workInfos.get();
    for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
        WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
        if (state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED) {
            UUID workerId = workInfo.getId();
            Log.d(TAG, "found enqueued work with id " + workerId);
            // BUT HOW DO I TELL WHAT TIME THIS WORK IS SCHEDULED TO RUN?
        }
    }
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: *but it would still be useful to know when -- in the absence of other factors -- the work is likely to run* - Why? What do you plan to do with that information?

Comment: @Luksprog to provide this information to the user... e.g. in a case where the periodic work updates a chart in a widget, the user knows when the work last ran (to update the chart) because the information is provided on the chart, and it is useful for them to know how long they have to wait until the chart will next be updated.

Comment: And also useful to know for support reasons.  I have one user where the periodic work seems vanish completely... so that auto updating of the widget stops.  The work queue appears to be completely empty based on log output.  The "next update time" is a useful indicator as to whether things are still ticking along OK or whether the "clock" has stopped.

Comment: Ok, but how would the WorkManager  provide you with this information if the task is set to be executed when some constraints are met? For example, if the task requires data connectivity the WorkManager can't possibly guess when that would be available(like today or after 3 weeks). Any information like this would be unreliable at best. The tasks are guaranteed to run, if you can replicate the missing tasks you should create an issue with the WorkManager library.

Comment: It's quite simple really... the work info can specify as much information about the work as possible, including timing and other constraints... it's up to the developer to decide how to use that information, e.g. how much to present to the user.

Comment: For example, if I can query a work item and determine that it is due to run in 10 mins time, subject to network constraint, then I can ignore network and just tell the user that the widget will refresh in ~10 mins time (they will already know it is subject to network because data needs to be fetched)... or give the full information e.g. "widget will refresh in ~10 mins time subject to available network and device being awake".

Comment: At present, so far as I can tell, I simply cannot find out any of this information even if I wanted to.  I did think that maybe I could execute `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler` from within the code, and parse that... but major hassle and also wouldn't work where jobscheduler is not being used (would also have to `adb shell dumpsys alarm`).  Would be far preferable if the API could provide this information.

Answer (score 4):

I found only 2 ways to "work around" this:

**Prerequistions**

Don't use periodic work! Always schedule the next periodic work manually with a `OneTimeWorkRequest` instead.

**Workaround 1:**

- when creating the `WorkRequest` you will call `setInitialDelay`. After enqueing the request, you can get it's id => save this id in a database with the execution time (and maybe policy infos and whatever you want), then you can always query the database and get the next execution time
- when a `WorkRequest` is executed, remove it from the database and then schedule the next "periodic" task manually as a `OneTimeWorkRequest`

**Workaround 2:**

- add 2 custom tag like "HasRunAt" and "RunAt:TIME_TO_RUN" to all your `WorkRequests`
- then get all `WorkInfos` like `WorkManager.getInstance().getWorkInfosByTag("HasRunAt")` and check their tags and parse the one that starts with "RanAt:"...

**Conclusion**

No solution is beautiful and I would like to have the ability of following as well:

- get the exectuion time, policy, ... from a `WorkInfo`
- get the `InputData` from the `WorkInfo` - then you could put all the extra info you want to access to this data and get it from there instead...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when they added it, but since posting my question there is now [WorkInfo.getNextScheduleTimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkInfo#getNextScheduleTimeMillis()).  So the only change to the code in my original question is to add this:

```
WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> workInfos = workManager.getWorkInfosByTag("mywork");

try {
    List<WorkInfo> workInfoList = workInfos.get();
    for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
        WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
        if (state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED) {
            UUID workerId = workInfo.getId();
            long nextScheduled = workInfo.getNextScheduleTimeMillis();
            Log.d(TAG, "found enqueued work with id " + workerId + " scheduled to run next at " + nextScheduled);
        }
    }
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```